# Select translation for given string

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am beginner in SQL and trying to design a query. I use my database for storing translations of different strings (which are used in UIs of different products).

My database contains 4 tables:

- **String** (id, name, lang_id):

"lang_id" is FK references "id" from "Language" table

- **Copy** (id, name)
- **Language** (id, name)
- **Translation** (id, string_1, string_2):

"string_1" and "string_2" are FKs that reference "id" from "String" table.

All my tables are using InnoDB engine, except **Copy** table which uses MyISAM engine and contains fulltext index on "name" column. I have triggers to ensure that IDs of strings in "String" and "Copy" tables match.

**Use case:**

User wants to translate new strings (which are not in DB yet) from english to German. User wants to find a reference translations for a string "Login" in order to reuse it and keep consistency.

User submits data (for example using a form on the website):

- Input language: English
- Output language: German
- String: Login

What user wants to get:

All strings from DB, which contain word "Login" and their corresponding German translation.

What I have so far:
ID of English language is 1,
ID of German language is 2

```
SELECT * FROM String s 
JOIN (SELECT id FROM Copy 
      WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('Login')) r 
ON s.id = r.id WHERE s.language = 1
```

That returns all strings in English, containing "Login".

I cannot figure what to do next, I think I should somehow join this result with "Translation" table.

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

P.S. I am using MySQL 5.5 (that's why I have this "Copy" table) and I understand that it might be better to use search engine for such tasks, but I want to accomplish it without one.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

For example I have:

```
       String                         Translation               Language
|id| name     | lang_id |     |id| string_1 | string_2 |      |id| name |
-------------------------     --------------------------      -----------
| 1| Good     |    1    |     |1 |    1     |     2    |      | 1| En   |
| 2| Gut      |    2    |     |2 |    4     |     3    |      | 2| De   |          
| 3| Good day |    1    |
| 4| Guten Tag|    2    |
```

I search for "Good", input lang "En", output lang "De", want to get result:

```
| Good     | Gut       |
| Good day | Guten Tag |
```

**EDIT**

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aaa4f/1/0)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: can you provide an insert script for your test data? btw do you only have english and german in your table? otherwise this would be a very inefficient database design (every string you translate has to be joined with every other language in your translation table)

Comment: Can the `Translation` table hold the ID for the english word in both `string_1` or `string_2`, or will it always be one of them?

Comment: @MartinParkin Always one of them, can be in `string_1` or `string_2`.

Comment: @JeremyC. A lot of languages. I am sorry, I will provide scripts tomorrow, they are on my working PC. Basically, I just insert English string and all translations separately into `String` and then insert all possible connections between them,without duplication, into `Translation`.

Comment: @Strawberry I am sorry, I will provide proper DDLs tomorrow. I added an example to my question above.

Comment: @Strawberry I added link to jsfiddle.

Comment: @JeremyC. I added link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select il.name, tl.name
from String il
join Translation t on (t.string_1 = il.id)
join String tl on (tl.id = t.string_2)
where (il.lang_id = [id_of_initial_lang]) and 
      (tl.lang_id = [id_of_translated_lang]) and 
      (il.name like '%[searchText]%')
union
select il.name, tl.name
from String il
join Translation t on (t.string_2 = il.id)
join String tl on (tl.id = t.string_1)
where (il.lang_id = [id_of_initial_lang]) and 
      (tl.lang_id = [id_of_translated_lang]) and 
      (il.name like '%[searchText]%')
```

Comment: It is almost it, but your solution works only if source string is on the left side (in `string_1`) of `Translation`.

Comment: Isn't this what you want? Your use case mentions _All strings from DB, which contain word "Login" and their corresponding German translation._ There is no sense in searching all the strings in all languages. Do you want to translate from one language to another or?

Comment: Yes, I need to translate from one language to another, but in `Translate` table, `id` of an English string can be in `string_1` or `string_2`. So we need to check both.

Comment: I slightly modified it to use my fulltext index, but overall it is working fine, thank you.